# Python. Поиск строки в файле python

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла `order_fix.txt` и `listdir.txt` необходимо проверить каждую строку из файла `listdir.txt`проверить на наличие такой же строки в `order_fix.txt`
Написал такой скрипт:

```
end_list = open('end_list.txt','w')
listdir = open('listdir.txt')
order = open('order_fix.txt')

for line in listdir.readlines():
   if line in open('order_fix.txt').read():
       end_list.write(line)
```

но он выполняется очень долго при ~2kk строк в файле `listdir.txt` больше 5ч.
Есть какой то вариант что бы ускорить этот процесс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно как-то так:

```
end_list = open('end_list.txt','w')
listdir = open('listdir.txt')
order_set = set(open('order_fix.txt').readlines())

for line in listdir.readlines():
   if line in order_set:
       end_list.write(line)
```

У вас для **каждой** строки в listdir, вы заново вычитываете весь order_fix. Но чтение с диска - достаточно тяжёлая операция. Поэтому там, где возможно, нужно стараться вычитывать файл только один раз в оперативную память и работать с данными уже в памяти.

Кроме этого, поиск вхождения гораздо быстрее производится в `set`, чем в списке, поэтому если нужно много и активно искать по большому списку, лучше построить из него один раз `set`, и искать уже в нём.

PS: Напишите, пожалуйста, насколько быстрее мой код работает по сравнению с вашим, мне любопытно ))

UPD: Ещё не вижу в вашем коде, где у вас выполняется закрытие файлов. Вы его  выполняете? Если нет, то файлы всегда стоит закрывать после того, как закончили работу с ними. А лучше вообще всюду, где это возможно, работать с файлами только при помощи менеджера контекста.